# Hiding sidebar and toggling bootstrap class on main body

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Currently in my rails application I have a site that is built on a bootstrap framework. The page is divided into a main body `col-md-9` and a persistent sidebar `col-md-3`. I have incorporated this Javascript:

```
  $("#sidebar-toggle").click(function(){
    $("#sidebar").toggle();
  });
```

It does exactly what I want it to do but I would also like to toggle the bootstrap class of the main body between `col-md-9` and `col-md-10 col-md-offset-1` depending on if the sidebar is active or not.

I know about `.addClass` and `.removeClass` but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into a `.toggle` function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: When you toggle your sidebar, which attribute of the element `#sidebar` actually toggles? I mean, could you please provide the HTML of this element (`#sidebar`) before and after it toggles. (right click on the element in the Chrome Browser and press `inspect` button to its actual state on the page in current moment of time)

Comment: The `.toggle()` JS function toggles between `.show()` and `.hide()` so it's changing the sidebar to `display: none` completely removing it from the page.   

`<div class="col-md-9 main-body"><%= yield %></div>` is the div containing the main body. which I would like to expand to `col-md-10 col-md-offset-1`
 '<div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs sidebar" id="sidebar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="290">' is the div that currently sits to the right of the main body. It switches to display none on button toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's toggleClass:

```
$( ".main-body" ).toggleClass( "col-md-9" );
$( ".main-body" ).toggleClass( "col-md-10" );
$( ".main-body" ).toggleClass( "col-md-offset-1" );
```

toggleClass will remove the class if it is present, or add it when it's not.

So if our div with class main-body has following class tag:

```
class="main-body col-md-9"
```

The first toggle will remove col-md-9, the second will add col-md-10 and the third will add col-md-offset-1.